# Using link_to in a rake task gives a no method - including helpers doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intercom

I have a rake task that I want to be sending emails to users using intercom. The issue I am having is that the link_to method does not exist.

I included the url_helpers at the top (not sure if its the right place). The error I am getting is: `NoMethodError: undefined method`link_to' for main:Object`

Please let me know if this is possible and if I am doing anything wrong.

here is the rake task:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

namespace :example do
desc "TODO"
task affiliate_bonus: :environment do

User.all.each do |user|
  if user.invited && user.invited.size > 0
    user_affiliate_bonus = AffiliateBonu.where(inviter_id: user.id)

    @the_user_af_bonus = 0
    @total_affiliate_bonus = 0

    user_affiliate_bonus.each do |ab|
      @total_affiliate_bonus = @total_affiliate_bonus.to_f + ab.btc_bonus_amount

      if ab.fulfilled == false
        @the_user_af_bonus = @the_user_af_bonus.to_f + ab.btc_bonus_amount

        if user.btc_wallet_address
          ab.fulfilled = true
          ab.save!
        end
      end
    end

    if @the_user_af_bonus >= 0 && user.affiliate_subscription

      @intercom = Intercom::Client.new(app_id: ENV["INTERCOM_APP_ID"], api_key: ENV["INTERCOM_APP_KEY"])
      user_receive = @intercom.users.create(email: user.email, user_id: user.id, :signed_up_at => Time.now.to_i)

      referral_link_text = link_to("https://www.example.com/ref/#{user.referral_link}", "https://www.example.com/ref/#{user.referral_link}")
      unsubscribe_text = link_to("click here", {:controller => "users", :action => "affiliate_unsubscribe", :user_id => user.id })
      balance_text = link_to('Balance', "https://example.com/users/balance")

      text = 
      "
        <% if user.first_name %>
        <p>Dear <%= user.first_name %>,</p>
        <% else %>
        <p>Dear Customer,</p>
        <% end %>

        <p>
          Your referral link: #{referral_link_text} has generated $ <%= @bonus %> for you this week. 
          <% if @bonus > 0 %>
            This amount was sent to your #{balance_text}.
          <% end %>
        </p>

        <p>Regards,</p>

        <p>George @<strong>Kaboom</strong></p>

        <p>--<br>
        PS. You are receiving this email update because your link has been used to sign up.</p>

        <p>To unsubscribe from your profit reports, #{unsubscribe_text}.</p>
      "

      @intercom.messages.create({ :message_type => 'email', subject: "Your Weekly Referral Earnings Report", :body => text, :template => "plain", :from => { :type => 'admin', :id   => "55070" }, :to => { type: "user", :id => user_receive.id } })
    end
  end
end
end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried moving this code into a template and then invoking the template from within the rake task?

Comment: @DMH I am not sure how this is done...

Comment: @dkp I get this error when I try to deploy on heroku "TypeError: wrong argument type ActionView::Base (expected Module"

Comment: You could just generate strings with `<a href=` tags directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to` instead of just `link_to` since helpers are not available to `lib` .